# SSIS flat file csv destination twice the size of bcp csv export

Tags: file, csv, ssis, size, bcp

I am having the problem that (despite the data being the exact same) when SSIS flat file destination to csv generates a file that is roughly twice the size of the CSV file generated by BCP.  The files that are created have the same data as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please provide more detail, and an example?

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb is that if the "same" file is twice as large as another file, check your encodings. This smells like the file generated from SSIS is storing as Unicode (16 bytes per character) versus BCP using (8 bytes per character)

To fix this, look at your Flat File Connection manager. There is a checkbox for Unicode and if it's checked, uncheck it.

(Yes, that's a gross generalization of code points, pages etc but good enough for this question)